# how to group data in a list

Tags: c#

I need  to group data of a list  in c#

ex: i have a data like this in a list c#

**i have a class called information.cs  with these properties  name,school, parent**

**ex data**

```
 name    school  parent

kumar      fes         All

manju      fes         kumar

anu         frank       kumar

anitha      jss          All

rohit       frank       manju

anill        vijaya      manju

vani         jss          kumar

soumya   jss           kumar

madhu     jss          rohit

 shiva       jss          rohit

vanitha       jss          anitha
 anu      jss          anitha
```

now taking this as an input   i wanted the  output  to be formated with a Hierarchical data
 when parent is **all** means it  is the topmost level 
     **kumar      fes         All**. 
 what i need to do here is i need to create an object[0] and then check in list  whether kumar exists as a parent in   the list if it exista then add those items as  under the object[0] as a parent

```
i need  to create one more oject under
**manju      fes         kumar

anu         frank       kumar**
```

what i wanted do here is iterate through the list anD then check the parent level based on

name    school  parent

```
kumar      fes         All -->obj[0]

manju      fes         kumar -->obj1[0]

anu         frank       kumar -->obj1[1]
```

for obj1--> obj[0]  will be parent like this  i need  to genarte  a list or observation class

```
    anitha      jss          All-->obj[1]
   vanitha       jss          anitha -->obj1[0]
       anu      jss           vanitha -->obj2[0]
```

here **obj2[0]-->obj1[0]-->obj[1]** will be an parent

like this i need  to  create a list or an observationclass  hope my Question is clear what i am trying  ask you people.
i wanted  to know  how i can create  an observationclass. 
any help would be really great.

hope my question is  clear

Comment: What version of C#/.NET?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  "like this i need to create a list or an observationclass"  -- You need to create a list of what?  Of children?  What is an observation class?

Comment: You can't even, like, line up the columns in your big lists?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Load data.
string[][] data = new string[][] {
    new string[] { "kumar", "fes", "All" },
    // etc.
};

ICollection<Information> infoData = data.Select(new Information(data)); // or however you load data.

// Find children of each node.
foreach(var info in infoData) {
    info.Children = infoData.Where(other => other.Name == info.Parent).ToList();
}

var rootChildren = infoData.Where(other => other.Name == "All");
```

Comment: thanks  for the  replay  stranger i  need  create  list  of 
class Person 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string School { get; set; } 
    public string Parent { get; set; } 
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; } 
}

Comment: like this i need to create a list

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that may work for you based on having a concrete class like this

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string School { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Load the people into a list and then iterate over it to find the children of any given person.

```
foreach (Person person in people)
{
    person.Children = people.Where(p => p.Parent == person.Name).ToList();
}
```

You can then work with your "main" parents with this.

```
var parents = people.Where(p => p.Parent == "All"); // .ToList() if you need a concrete list
```

Comment: thanks  for teh Anthony Pegram  here i am getting the  output in console application. i need  to store the  output in an collection list 
 how  cann i do it  any help would be great

Comment: @prince23 - That was a demo. In my code, `parents` will contain the data you need. If you need a concrete list, call `.ToList()` on it. Beyond that, happy coding.

Comment: Recursion isn't necessary, as you need to pass all elements exactly once, order doesn't matter, and you don't need extra hierarchical information.  Simple iteration would work more efficiently.

Comment: where  should i be  call.ToList(). would  you please let me kow

Comment: i wanted the  result  now to be   binded  to gridview  so i wanted  to result to be stored in list

Comment: i wanted the  syntax  how  to  do it

Comment: hi anthony, stranger, 
i wanted the same  concept  to be applied in silverlight and bind to gridview  so only wanted  the result to be  stored in collection list